# How to pass an image from java to flutter?

Tags: java, image, flutter, dart, bitmap

I am trying to pass an image from java to flutter. The image is in `bitmap` in java so I first try to convert it to `bytes[]` using:

on java side:

```
int byteCount = transferredImage.getAllocationByteCount(); // transferredImage is the bitmap
ByteBuffer buffer = ByteBuffer.allocate(byteCount); //Create a new buffer
transferredImage.copyPixelsToBuffer(buffer);
byte[] myByte = buffer.array();
```

Then on flutter side I read the image as `Uint8List` and create an `img.Image` object from it:

```
img.Image styleImage = img.Image.fromBytes(
        imgWidth,
        imgHeight,
        transferredBytes,
    );
```

This works, without causing any errors but the image displayed using `Image.memory(img.encodeJpg(styleImage))` always has a blue tint. The bitmap on java side is fine but when converted to `bytes[]` and displayed in flutter it has a blue tint..

So I assumed some important information may have been dropped during conversion to `bytes` using my above method, I then convert the image to an image format and then transfer the bytes:

at java side:

```
ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
transferredImage.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, baos);
byte bytes []= baos.toByteArray();
```

on flutter side:

```
img.Image styleImage = img.Image.fromBytes(
        imgWidth,
        imgHeight,
        transferredBytes,
    );
```

But this does not work and creates an error:

> RangeError (index): Index out of range: index should be less than
> 321512: 322560

If possible, I would prefer to have my first attempt work as it is really fast, so is there any way I can get this to work ?

Thanks

Comment: on flutter side try `Image.memory(transferredBytes)`

Comment: Yes, that works in displaying the image, but I want it in ``img.Image`` as I need to resize it and process it further.

Comment: I dont only want to display the image but process it on flutter side such as resize and crop. creating an ``img.Image`` from the png/jpeg bytes produces the range error as mentioned in my question

Comment: I have, when creating an image using ``img.Image.fromBytes( )`` and I use ``img.decodeJpg()`` it says I cant use an ``Image`` here and I canot use ``img.encodeJpg()`` because the image is already of type ``Uint8List``

Comment: @pskink, I dont know why you deleted your earlier comment but your suggested method of ``img.Image finalImage = img.copyResize(img.decodePng(predictions), width: 384, height: 384);`` works perfectly. Thanks